# MySQL days before based on setting in other table

Tags: mysql, date, offset

The current query checks if the a it is the customers birthday today and if the processTime is this hour. This works like a charm. However we want to adjust the query and also send customers a email x days before there birthday. That depends on the dayOffset setting in birthday_settings.

dayOffset can be in the range of -365 to +365.

What should I adjust to the below query. The birthday column is a date column

```
SELECT firstName, lastName, birthday, FROM 
    birthday_customers C
    INNER JOIN
    birthday_settings S
        ON C.customerId = S.customerId
WHERE 
    MONTH(birthday) = MONTH(NOW()) 
    AND DAY(birthday) = DAY(NOW())
    AND processTime = HOUR(NOW())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just subtract the number of days from the current time:

```
SELECT firstName, lastName, birthday
FROM birthday_customers C INNER JOIN
     birthday_settings S
     ON C.customerId = S.customerId
WHERE MONTH(birthday) = MONTH(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), interval s.DayOffset day) AND
      DAY(birthday) = DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), interval s.DAYOffset day) AND
      processTime = HOUR(NOW())
```